# Implicit declaration of function 'uart_isr_register' despite including library and espressif seeing the function and can shows me the definition

Tags: visual-studio-code, include, esp32, uart, espressif-idf

This is my first post here, so please let me know if I'm doing something wrong. I'm trying to create an interrupt-based UART receive task on my ESP32S3. It should be straightforward, but unfortunately, I'm encountering an issue. When I compile the code in Visual Studio Code in combination with the Espressif IDE, I get the following error: "implicit declaration of function 'uart_isr_register'; did you mean 'gpio_isr_register'?" To the best of my knowledge, this error typically occurs when a library is not found. However, I've included it with the line '#include "driver/uart.h," and if I go to the definition, it finds it perfectly in the UART code."

below my included libraries:

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "esp_attr.h"
```

and here the function where the error occurs:

```
void serialComInit(void){
    const uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 115200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
        .source_clk = UART_SCLK_DEFAULT,
    };
    // We won't use a buffer for sending data.
    struct receiveDataObj rxObject[1];
    uart_param_config(UART_NUM_1, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(UART_NUM_1, TXD_PIN, RXD_PIN, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE);
    uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_1, RX_BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
    uart_isr_register(UART_NUM_1, uart_rx_intr_handler, rxObject, ESP_INTR_FLAG_IRAM, NULL);
    uart_enable_rx_intr(UART_NUM_1);
}
```

the function it points to is shown below:

```
void IRAM_ATTR uart_rx_intr_handler(struct receiveDataObj *rxPtr){
    static const char *RX_TASK_TAG = "RX_TASK";
    esp_log_level_set(RX_TASK_TAG, ESP_LOG_INFO);
    uint8_t* data = (uint8_t*) malloc(RX_BUF_SIZE+1);
    while (1) {
        rxPtr->rxBytes = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_1, data, RX_BUF_SIZE, portMAX_DELAY);
        if (rxPtr->rxBytes > 0) {
            data[rxPtr->rxBytes] = 0;
            rxPtr->incomingData = (char*)malloc(rxPtr->rxBytes + 1);
                if (rxPtr->incomingData) {
                    memcpy(rxPtr->incomingData, data, rxPtr->rxBytes);
                    rxPtr->incomingData[rxPtr->rxBytes] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
                }
            ESP_LOGI(RX_TASK_TAG, "Read %d bytes: '%s'", rxPtr->rxBytes, data);
            //ESP_LOG_BUFFER_HEXDUMP(RX_TASK_TAG, data, rxBytes, ESP_LOG_INFO);
            if(strstr(rxPtr->incomingData, "+CMQTTRXSTART:") != NULL ){
                ESP_LOGI("COMS","RECEIVED MQTT COMMAND");
                mqttCommand = true;
            }
        }
    }
    free(data);
}
```

I've tried placing the function in different files. i've added ifndef's. excluded the gpio library but that only resulted in the error "did you mean ledc_isr_register?" So I don't know what to do at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "implicit declaration of a function" happens when a function is called before being declared, not when "a library isn't found". Declaration can be done in your own code before it uses the function or in a header file.

You're expecting to `uart_isr_register()` to be declared in `drivers/uart.h` - it is not.

You can confirm this by looking at the contents of that file. ESP-IDF is open source, so you can inspect the file in its Github repo.

According to [ESP-IDF's documentation](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/8fc8f3f47997aadba21facabc66004c1d22de181/docs/en/migration-guides/release-5.x/5.0/peripherals.rst#uart), was removed in ESP-IDF 5.0 as the UART driver now registers for the interrupt itself. You can find this easily by searching the repository for `uart_isr_register`. The solution is just to remove this line of code as it's no longer needed.